# Format Middle Of The String With Thousand Separators & Decimal Point

Tags: vb.net

I want to know how to format middle of the string with thousand separators.

I try following method. It's not working.

`TextBox1.Text = "This Amount" & FORMAT(CStr(3458185.45),2) & " Deducted"`

Someone please help me to do this.

`TextBox1.Text = "This Amount Rs. 3,458,185.45 Deducted"`

**Edited**

Actually, that figure came from variable. So I want to format that variable as string.

```
Dim didAmount as decimal = 3458485.45
TextBox1.Text = "This Amount" & FORMAT(CStr(didAmount),2) & " Deducted"
```

**Edited 02**

Finally I found how to do this

```
Dim didAmount as decimal = 3458485.45
TextBox1.Text = "This Amount " & didAmount.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) & " Deducted."
```

Comment: You can't format a string. You can only format a number as a string. Don't convert the number to a string first. The formatting does the conversion.

Comment: jmcilhinney, Sorry I forget to enter variable. I edited my question.

Comment: Don't answer your question in the question. If you solve the problem yourself, post an answer yourself. You should spend some time in the Help Center to learn how this site works. It is not a forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you don't convert the number to a string first, then try to format that string. That means that the `CStr` in your original code was the issue. In this particular case, while the concatenation (in your "answer") is not wrong, it's not really the most appropriate option. It would make the code more readable to use `String.Format`:

```vb
TextBox1.Text = String.Format("This Amount {0:N} Deducted.", didAmount)
```

If you really need to specify a culture then you can do that:

```vb
TextBox1.Text = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "This Amount {0:N} Deducted.", didAmount)
```

If you don't need to specify a culture then string interpolation is better still:

```vb
TextBox1.Text = $"This Amount {didAmount:N} Deducted."
```

You can also use the invariant culture like this:

```vb
TextBox1.Text = FormattableString.Invariant($"This Amount {didAmount:N} Deducted.")
```